# Gaussian Naive Bayes classifiers - how is the data distributed?

Tags: classification, gaussian, bayesian

Gaussian Naive Bayes assumes that the continuous values associated with each class are distributed according to a Gaussian distribution.

How can data be distributed Normally if it only has two classes, for example?